# Highcharts data from MySql with laravel ,But html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I use Laravel get data from database use mysql.The data is get and I format the data then transferred to homepage use compact function.

The homepage use highcharts receive the json,but it doesn't work.
Please help find out what's wrong whit the code.
Thanks very much!

laravel code

```
        //title标题
        $title = "GoldenQuant";

        //获取灰金净值的数据
        $res = HistoryData::where('product_id','1')->orderBy('time','desc')->get();

        $data = array();
        //将获取的数据重新排版
        if(count($res) > 0){
            foreach( $res as $value){
                $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$value['time']));
                $data[] = [ $timestamp , $value['cumulativeNet']];
            }
        }


        //highchart设置内容

        //x坐标轴
        $highchart['xAxis'] = [ 'title' => [ 'text' => '时间' ] ];

        //y坐标轴
        $highchart['yAxis'] = [ 'title' => [ 'text' => '净值' ] ];

        //数据
        $highchart['series'] = [ 'name'=>'灰金净值' , 'data' => $data ];

        $highchart['rangeSelector'] = array( 'selected' => '1' );

        return view('index.index',compact('title','highchart'));
    }
```

Homepage javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#highchart').highcharts('StockChart',
                                 {!! json_encode($highchart)!!}
      )
      })</script>
```

The json

```
{
    "xAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "时间"
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "净值"
        }
    },
    "series": {
        "name": "灰金净值",
        "data": [
            [
                1441900800,
                1
            ],
            [
                1439222400,
                1
            ]
        ]
    },
    "rangeSelector": {
        "selected": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: `series` should be an array of objects, not an object. Like this: `series: [{ ... }]`.

Comment: thanks.I change the code like you say, then the code worked.